# After updating android studios i.e the flamingo version, I am getting this error

Tags: android

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}.
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\saksh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar.
Cannot create mockable android.jar
C:\Users\saksh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33\android.jar

I tried updating the Android SDK platform, but the error is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the `android.jar` did not exist in `Android/sdk/platforms/android-33`.
I've downloaded the [Android SDK Platform 33](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKPlatform) and replaced the files in `Android/sdk/platforms/android-33` and the error was gone.